# can I pipe audio stream to multiple files (node js)

Tags: node.js, stream

Node server receives a stream of audio buffer, How to save this stream to multiple files every file contain 100 mega of buffer

```
writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
(stream).pipe(writeStream)
```

`fs.truncate()` and `fs.write()` don't work with writeStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a round service on the file or copying the file and truncate the original file to zero.

Comment: truncate not work with fs.createWriteStream(filename)

Comment: It's imposible to do that with `fs.createWriteStream()`.
Solved by use `fs.writFile()` then append to this file audio chunk and by `fs.statSync()` check file size if more than or equal 10 mega `fs.copy()` this file to new distination finally `fs.truncate()` to remove all buffer from file thanks Amr